# Why datepicker.parseDate is not working?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

According to [datepicker.parseDate reference](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate), this method accepts two parameters, a *format* and a *date* and try an exception if the *date not match the *format*. Perfect, but then, why [this piece of code](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/t2nNJ/) is not working?

```
function isDate(value) {
    var isDate = false;
    try {
        var dateFormat = "yy";
        $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, value);
        isDate = true;
    } catch (e) {}
    return isDate;
}
```

EDIT: I've found a simpler example. This returns an "Invalid date" exception.

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('yy', '2010');
```

Comment: "is not working" in what way?

Comment: It should return true or false but depending if you give a year or not and it returns always false

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs:

> 'Invalid date' if the date is invalid, such as '31/02/2007'

In other words, your string value actually has to be a full date. That gets turned into a Date object and then it formats it for you.

Try:

`$.datepicker.parseDate('yy', '18/10/2011');`

Comment: I've executed `$.datepicker.parseDate('yy', '18/10/2011');` in jsfiddle directly and it still throws an exception :(

Comment: check the reference to jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var dateObject = $.datepicker.parseDate('d/m/yy', '18/10/2011');
```

One thing that surprised me is jQueryUI's symbols used in the date format string were a little different than I was used to seeing in C#.  Here is the link that describes what they mean:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate

Answer (score 0):

try either

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('yyyy', '2010');
```

or

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('yy', '10');
```